# nginx Sinatra head meta refresh 404

Tags: nginx, sinatra, refresh, nginx-location

For some reason, a page is forwarding to an `nginx`-served 404 page.  The site is working except for this one page.  On my landing page, I have the following in the header:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=/second">`

Even hard coding `http://mydomain.local/second` serves up the same 404.

This is a `Sinatra` deployment.

```
get "/second" do
  @title = "my Title"
  erb :index
end
```

I am thinking maybe my `locations` directive in `nginx.conf` is a bit screwy:

```
location / {
    autoindex                       off;
    try_files                       $uri $uri/ $uri/$request =404;
    index                           /;
    }
```

Anybody have any insight why `Sinatra` wouldn't capture the route and just serve up the file?  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Lets break this down:

```
autoindex off;
```

You don't need to specify this, it's off by default.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/$request =404;
```

Try and match requests to files in this order, serve the first one which matches. If none match, return 404. Your request is `http://mydomain.local/second`, so you are telling Nginx to look for:

1. webroot/second
2. webroot/second/
3. webroot/second/GET /second HTTP/1.1
4. Return 404

The index directive tells Nginx how to handle requests ending with a slash, you would normally specify files likely to be index files within your project, eg index.php, index.html etc. You don't really use this and `try_files` together as they serve a similar purpose.

Also worth noting that Nginx adds a trailing slash to any request which doesn't have one and doesn't end with a file extension, so it may also be the case that `get "/second" do` needs to change to `get "/second/" do`, as I doubt Sinatra ever sees the request without the trailing slash appended

Comment: 1.  Ah good to know.  2.  Sinatra uses a `/` nomenclature, so `$uri`should work.  In essence I'm asking for `GET /second`, but `404`'s.  In any case, even with the refresh and a link on that page set to `/second/`, I'm still getting the `404`.

Comment: Does it not run as a separate server?

Comment: Does what run as a separate server?  `Sinatra` works after `Rack` and `Passenger`, but it's part of the stack.  I have a handful of sites whose routes are requested as `/alpha`.  So there's something fishy going on.

Comment: I have no experience of Sinatra, but I'm assuming it creates it's own http server, running on its own ip:port, right?

Comment: Nope.  That's all handled by `nginx`.  Sinatra is a framework only.  You can use `webrick` as well, or `Apache`.  It's quite the quick little framework that is `Rack`-based.  Recently it's been measured as 7x faster than `Rails`.

Comment: Interesting, looking at other setups with Sinatra they seem to define the root directive in Nginx as the location of your Sinatra app and then dont specify a location block for requests with a single `/`. Wht does the rest of your nginx.conf look like?

Comment: Ya that gets passed off to `Sinatra` to the `app.rb`, then through the routes files.  So `/` is heard, `Sinatra` does the `ruby` magic, then outputs to a chosen template (many available) for output.  So a site root directive example is `/usr/local/www/site/public/`, where the last directory is only viewable to the public.  So `/css` is actually `/public/css`.  All the app logic and associated files lie above `/public'.  Helpers, routes, admin files, and upload receive.  http://sinatrarb.com/intro.html Look under Routes.

Comment: Says `get '/foo' do # Does not match "GET /foo/"`Humour me and put a trailing slash in your Sinatra config to make it `get "/second/" do`. Nginx will be adding a trailing slash before the request gets to Sinatra. If I curl my server `curl -v http://127.0.0.1/code` Nginx responds `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently Location: http://127.0.0.1/code/`

Comment: Oh I did.  Didn't work.  And I remember tripping over this when I started `Sinatra` before.  That's why I sniffed out my other `Sinatra` routes.  Even if `nginx` does an internal rewrite, `Sinatra` might remove that afterwards, given the policy of their `routes`.

Comment: Your `nginx` 301 sounds like an internal `Server`-level redirect.  That's how you force SSL using a redirect to another `Server` entry listening on port 443.